# wordpress 4.0: move the form to enter comments up above the list of comments

Tags: php, wordpress

how move the form to enter comments up above the list of comments in wordpress 4.0?

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h3 id="comments">Комментарии <span class="label label-primary"><?php comments_number('0', '1', '%');?></span> </br> <small>к теме &#8220;<?php the_title(); ?>&#8221;</small></h3>

        <ol class="commentlist">
        <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'rubulat_comment' ) ); ?>
        </ol>

        <div class="navigation lead text-center">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_comments_link() ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php next_comments_link() ?></div>
        </div>
     <?php endif; ?>


    <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?>

    <div id="respond">

    <h3><?php comment_form_ti
    tle( 'Написать комментарий', 'Написать комментарий к %s' ); ?></h3>


    <div class="cancel-comment-reply">
        <small><?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?></small>
    </div>

    <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
    <p>Вы должны <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">войти</a> чтобы добавить свой комментарий.</p>
    <?php else : ?>

    <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

    <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

    <p>Вы вошли как <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Выйти из этого аккаунта">Выход &raquo;</a></p>

    <?php else : ?>

    <p><input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
    <label for="author"><small>Имя <?php if ($req) echo "(обязательно)"; ?></small></label></p>

    <p><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" <?php if ($req) echo "aria-required='true'"; ?> />
    <label for="email"><small>Почта (скрыто) <?php if ($req) echo "(обязательно)"; ?></small></label></p>

    <!-- p><input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" />
    <label for="url"><small>Сайт</small></label></p -->

    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- p><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> Вы можете использовать эти теги: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p -->

    <p><textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>

    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Добавить комментарий" />
    <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
    </p>
    <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>

    </form>
```

the form must be under, the block with the number of comments.
under form for entering comments , should be a list of comments.
Please tell me that I need to change in the code

Comment: maybe...wordpress 4.0

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress 4.0 the comment form is displaying under the comments in default. Generally you can change the position of the code `<?php comment_form(); ?>` in themes `comments.php` to change the position of comments form.